# Como adicionar campos billing na página edit-account do Woocommerce! (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Pessoal como consigo adicionar campos que já são default do woocommerce na página minha conta? tentei da seguinte forma: 
mas não objetive o resultado esperado.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'add_fields_to_edit_account_form');
function add_fields_to_edit_account_form( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_cpf'] = array(
        'label'         => __('CPF', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('CPF', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'      => true,
        'class'         => array('form-row-last'),
     );

    return $fields;
}
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se este CPF estiver vindo através do plugin *WooCommerce Extra Checkout Fields*, o método via billing em uma array provavelmente não vai entender essas informações em *woocommerce_edit_account_form*. A maneira mais fácil, porém menos dinâmica, seria puxar essa informação através da função *wp_get_current_user()*. Abaixo você pode ver como fiz (aliás, segui a mesma formatação da *form-edit-account.php* do WooCommerce):

```
//add cpf field
function add_cpf_field() {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    ?><p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="billing_cpf"><?php esc_html_e( 'CPF', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="billing_cpf" id="billing_cpf" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->billing_cpf ); ?>" />
    </p><?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'add_cpf_field');


//save cpf field
function save_cpf_details( $user_id ){
    $cpf = ! empty( $_POST['billing_cpf'] ) ? wc_clean( $_POST['billing_cpf'] ) : '';
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_cpf', $cpf );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_cpf_details' );

//validate cpf field
function validate_cpf( $validation_error  ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_cpf'] ) ) {

    if(strlen($_POST['billing_cpf']) < 11 ) //condição básica de pelo menos 11 caracteres
        $validation_error->add( 'error', __( 'Your CPF is not valid.', 'woocommerce' ),'');
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details_errors','validate_cpf', 10, 1 );
```

Espero ter ajudado! ;)

Comment: Sim mais mesmo assim ele não pega as configurações de campos obrigatorios e não salva os dados no banco. obrigado!

Comment: Como assim configuração de campos obrigatórios? De qualquer forma, atualizei o código e acrescentei um hook para salvar o campo de CPF, assim caso a pessoa queira alterar direto na página da conta, agora ela pode.

Comment: Entendi... acrescentei outro hook para validar... só não fiz uma condição mais avançada com relação a CPF.

Comment: Blz Brother.. vou testar aqui.. acredito que é algo bem parecido com isso! Obrigado.

Comment: Qualquer coisa, tamo aí! ;)